# Splitting word file using regex python

Tags: python, regex, ms-word, document

I am trying to split word files (`.doc` and `.docx`) into multiple word (`.doc`)or text (`txt`) files - whichever is easier to split into.

Each `.doc` or `.docx` file has at least one contract number, identified by `contract-number1 = re.findall('CONTRACT NUMBER\n+(.*)', text)` or `contract-number2 = re.findall('CONTRACT NUMBER\s+(.........)', text)`.

I am trying to write a code that:

- given `n` contract numbers in the document, splits and saves the word document into `n` documents. For example, if the word document has the following text:

  `contract number 03-4E2204 blah blah balahds jdf scdhfdskv dasjcnfd fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsiffjks d fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsi d fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsi contract number          56-24834h idnfoskfiwedc sfeiofnlfnfkw fdoisfrjkfn fsoifoslk`

  then the code should split the text and create 2 documents (`.doc` or `.txt`, whichever is easier) as follows:

  **document 1:** `contract number 03-4E2204 blah blah balahds jdf scdhfdskv dasjcnfd fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsiffjks d fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsi d fds kwdcs feridwe freedewkf ewiddsk ddsi`

  **document 2:** `contract number          56-24834h idnfoskfiwedc sfeiofnlfnfkw fdoisfrjkfn fsoifoslk`

**Code**

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import docx2txt
import textract
import antiword

# setting directory
os.chdir('/Users/aartimalik/Documents/GitHub/revenue_procurement/pdfs/bidsummaries-doc-test')
text = textract.process('/Users/aartimalik/Documents/GitHub/revenue_procurement/pdfs/bidsummaries-doc/100831R0.doc_2026.doc')
text = text.decode("utf-8")
```

I am not sure how to proceed or if it's even possible to do this. Googling showed how to split documents by page, page range, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you so much!

Comment: You could use this as the pattern to get all the matches `\bcontract number\b[\s\S]*?(?=\bcontract number\b|$)`  See https://regex101.com/r/D6DGx0/1 And then you can use re.findall to get all the matches and store each item to a file.

Comment: the hard part here is to figure out the delimiters in a single file -- in your example if you do `re.split('patternhere', text)` does the result give you the 'documents' you expect?

Comment: Trying this. Also, is there a way to save these splits as word documents in a specific directory...?

Comment: Using this pattern isn't working with re.split.